# Limit of a Sine Fourier Series of a Function without finding the series

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

For the following question, should the approach just be find the limit of $f(x)$ and use that?

Any advice to tackling this?

The Fourier Sine series of the function

$$f(x)= \frac{1}{2}+\frac{|4x-\pi|}{4x-\pi}\cos(x), \;\;\; 0\leq x\leq \pi,
$$

converges. Without using a series or integration, find the limit of the Fourier Sine series of $f(x)$ and sketch the limit for $-3\pi\leq x\leq 3\pi$.

Comment: fractions display much better using display math '$$' instead of '$'. Also you need '\' in front of 'cos' and 'sin' in order for these functions to display correctly. I fixed for those for you.

Answer (score 0):

The function you have specified is smooth in $[0,\pi]$ except at $x=\pi/4$, and extends periodically to a function with left- and right- limits everywhere, and left- and right- derivatives everywhere. So the Fourier series for the function converges to the mean of the left- and right-hand limits at every point.